# How to stop accelerometer sensor

Tags: android, listener, accelerometer, shake

I am using exactly this code in this example

http://android.themind-lab.com/post/2010/05/14/Dont-shake-my-phone!-How-to-detect-shake-motion-on-Android-phone.aspx

What should i include in MyMethod() to stop the listener and don`t wait for another shake after MyMethod() is called the first time?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The line

**sensorMgr.unregisterListener(this);**

will make the system stop sending you onSensorChanged updates

Comment: Thank you this works for me too. But how am I able to `restart` the Listener? I implemented a pause button but I cant call my `registerListener` method to restart the Sensor.

Answer (score 2):

finally found the answer:

this is not enough for unregister the listener, you also need to set your SensorEventListener to null

```
sensorMgr.unregisterListener(this);
msensorlistener = null;
```

this trick works very good,

hope it helps.